# How to convert DAT to MP3 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: video, mp3, convert, video-conversion, soundconverter

I have a question:

How can I convert a `.DAT` or other formats to `mp3`?

Do we have a good tool for doing that? If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of software for this purpose :

**WinFF** --> Official site [Here](http://winff.org/html_new/)

**Avidemux**

You can see this [Page](http://solitarygeek.com/linux/linux-ubuntu-video-converter-dat-converter)

You can also install Wine and then install **FormatFactory**

Comment: Thank you...I found it and download and works...but was not able to convert to mp3

Comment: try to search for libmp3lame encoder and install it

Comment: see the edit now and try wine

Comment: You see I installed libmp3lame but nothing happened

Comment: Pardon, FormatFactory is windows format of winFF?

Comment: +1 winff works good, ubuntu16.04 and Linux Mint, `apt install winff`

Answer (score 0):

Install [Dat to Mp3 converter](http://www.asoftwareplus.com/dat-to-mp3-converter.html) and then run it with wine